# Updating table on the basis of dynamic query result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which stores SQL SELECT statements and stored procedures as followings:

```
 SQLId SQLText
 1     IsExistingPlan
 2     IsProcessed
```

The stored procedures designed to return bit data type(true/false).
I have another table, which contains different conditions:

```
 CondId CondGrpId   SQLId  nFlag
 1      1            1     1
 2      1            2     0
 3      2            1     1
```

I want to create a temporary table on the basis of the output of executed SQLTexts. The table will have a column "CondVal". The value of the column will be true/false depending on the return value of the procedure true/false.The table structure would be as following:

```
 CondId CondGrpId   CondVal  nFlag
 1      1            1     1
 2      1            0     0
 3      2            1     1
```

How I can do the required set of operations effectively by SQL Query?

Comment: Can you elaborate this `The value of the column will be 1/0 depending on the return value of the procedure true/false`

Comment: Have you looked into Dynamic SQL?   Is there something specific about it that you do not know how to do?

Comment: The stored procedures will be returning true or false. The "CondVal" column value will be updated with the returned value of the procedures(true/false).

Comment: @user3458122 fine, But how you will know which row has to be updated in `CondVal` column. What is the relation ?

Comment: It would be depending on the CondId column.